# What are those hg-bundle files in my .hg Mercurial directory and are they required?

Tags: mercurial

We're using Mercurial (with TortoiseHg).

Our repository has been growing steadily in size.  Looking in the .hg folder, I see loads of `hg-bundle` files, most of which are fairly large (from 2-20 MB)

Are these necessary?  Are they duplicating changes that are already saved in the `store\` directory?

My understanding is that remote pushes and pulls package up diffs into bundle files and send them over to various peer installations.

Do the bundle files get deleted after an `hg merge` or `hg update` command?  If not, are these files the residue that need to be manually deleted?

Any advice, much appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are either databases or copies of the files. If they are copies, it is for comparing files to see if they've changed.

As for deleting it, don't. Any control directory's (begin with `.`) should never be tampered with under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

These files live in that particular .hg directory, but they will not propagate around.  I find it annoying, so I do:

mv dirname dirname-stupidly-big
(cd dirname-stupidly-big; hg clone -U . ../dirname)

and now dirname is reasonably sized.